# Where is the "Add package" lightbulb in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, asp.net-core-webapi

In C# in Visual Studio 2015 if you specify a name present in a package not currently referenced then the Lightbulb feature pops-up and suggests a package reference to add.

[[image]]

I can't seem to get this in Visual Studio 2017. Is there some extension I need to install or some other setting?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this class that you mentioned and other classed that included in the [.NET Core App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/), it looks like there is no such option ‘Add package ……’ like the following screenshot[image]. I have already reported this issue to the VS Product Team and please have a look at this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/32739/in-vs-2017-invoke-a-class-that-included-in-a-packa.html, then we need to waiting for the response from the VS Product Team Engineers

Comment: vs2015 has this feature and vs2017 doesn't? maybe we need install new extension or third party tool?

Comment: @BilliLoo, thank for your reminder, I tried to run the command: devenv /safemode to run the VS 2015 as safe mode, I can still get the option 'Add package....'. As far as I know, start Visual Studio in safe mode, loading only the default environment and services and no installed extensions will be loaded. If this feature depends on the specific extension or tool, this feature should not works with safe mode.